# Deleting uploaded files form Dropzone.js form

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I'm using [dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) for my project and I need to delete files from plugin upload zone (not from server) after I upload them. I need to get back to "Drop files here or click to upload" text after upload.

I'm trying to get same result that I would get when I'm using "Remove file" link under file icon. But when I try to achieve this programmatically the `removeFileEvent` won't trigger.

I tried both jquery `trigger('click');` and `dispatchEvent(event);`.

My code:

```
 var dropzone = new Dropzone('#uploadzone', 
    {
       url: 'uploaded_url.php',
       addRemoveLinks: true,
       init: function () 
       {
           this.on("success", function (file, response) 
           {
              var removeLink = $(file.previewElement).find('a.dz-remove');
              removeLink.trigger('click');
           });
       }
    );
```

Comment: have you tried their API method?? like `dropzone.removeFile(file)`

Comment: Nope, Didn't noticed that part in documentation. Tried it and it works. Thanks !

Comment: I will make it as answer so that it will be helpful for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the API given by dropzone

`dropzone.removeFile(file)`

[Docs](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#dropzone-methods)